# Excel: How to check for repeated numbers inside a cell

Tags: arrays, excel, math, numbers, repeat

I have an excel spreadsheet with numbers from 000 to 999 and am trying to find repeated numbers **inside**  a cell.

(So for example, printing 1 if the number is **022** , **555** or **115** and 0 if it isn't)

So far, I have not been able to find a solution.

Feel free to ask for more information and thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you read the cell as a string and then loop through the characters in the string, and for each iteration of said loop check if that character appears twice in the string?

Comment: It probably will work, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: You haven't tagged VBA. Does that mean you're looking for a formula-based solution?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with VBA as I mainly use languages like GML and don't use excel frequently. So yes, I am looking for a formula based solution if possible.

Comment: This not a programming question. It's just a list of poorly expressed requirements. Please reword the question and post your solving attempts.

Answer (score 3):

This will do: `=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(REPT({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},2),A1))>0,1,0)`

Note: If value in cell `A1` contains 2 repeated digits it will show 1 else 0. You can customize the repetition limit by changing 2 in the part **8,9},*2*)**.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one if you wanted to find repeated digits not necessarily next to each other:-

```
=IF(MAX(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"")))>1,1,0)
```

If the numbers are stored as 3-digit numbers and you wanted it to work for (e.g.) 001, would need:-

```
=IF(MAX(LEN(TEXT($A1,"000"))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT($A1,"000"),{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},"")))>1,1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in Range "A1:A100" and you want to locate repeated numbers in the range for instance, enter `=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,1,0)` in cell B1 and fill down. But if you want to check repetitions of specific numbers like 022, 555 or 115, enter `=IF(OR(AND(A1=022,COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1),AND(A1=555,COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1),AND(A1=115,COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1)),1,0)` in cell B1 and fill down.

Answer (score -1):

being a number, use arithmetics to break it into digits and then check if all are different.

the formula is

```
=INT(NOT(AND(INT(A1/100)<>INT(MOD(A1,100)/10),INT(A1/100)<>MOD(A1,10),INT(MOD(A1,100)/10)<>MOD(A1,10))))
```

let's analyze it step by step

first, `INT(A1/100)` extracts the first digit (the integer division by 100); then `INT(MOD(A1,100)/10)` extracts the second digit (the integer division by 10 of the modulo 100); and `MOD(A1,10)` extracts the last digit (the modulo 10).

next there are the three comparisons of difference `<>` first with second, second with third and first with third, combined with `AND()` and finally take the result, negate it `NOT()` and transforming it into an integer 0 or 1 with `INT()`

Comment: Perhaps add something to your post to clarify why the 11 in 2.11 is NOT to be considered.

Comment: The formula works with the examples provided. 1 being 001 and 121  returning 1 as habing two digits repeated.