# Excel: How to check for repeated numbers inside a cell 2

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, numbers, repeat

I have an excel spreadsheet with numbers from 0000 to 99999 (4-5 digits)
I am trying to find cells that contain up to 2 repeated digits only

(So for example, printing TRUE if the number is 0022 , 1010 , 55555 or 1112 and FALSE if it isn't)

I found partial solution in [38418690](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418690/excel-how-to-check-for-repeated-numbers-inside-a-cell) , however it didn't helped

Feel free to ask for more information and thanks in advance.

Comment: Do the repeated digits habe to be consecutiv? Is 1241 True or false?

Comment: Please reformulate your question and use some relevant data to accurately explain what should return `TRUE` and what `FALSE`. *"up to 2 repeated digits only"* could mean "a maximum of 2 repeated digits" or "2 instances of a repeated single digit"... If `1112` should return `TRUE` then you might reformulate with e.g. `if any digit is repeated`.

Comment: number contain 1 or 2 same digits = TRUE , if more it's FALSE (11223 for example). if ANY 2 digits repeat in same number no matter the position in number, but ONLY 1 or 2 specific digits.

Comment: 1241 is FALSE , since contain 3 different digits 1 , 2 , 4

Comment: So `1112` is FALSE or TRUE here? Everything is good, but `1112` made us confused, it really contradicts, can you put up few more examples. Where we can relate, So starting from `0000` till `99999` by your conditions you will have `1100` TRUE and rest is false is that correct

Comment: Can you try this formula once and let me know: `=LET(a,A2#,b,REPLACE(LEFT(a,4),3,0,"|"),c,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&b,"|",{1,2}),"|"),FILTER(a,(TAKE(c,,1)=DROP(c,,1))))` Change the `A2#` with your actual range of data.

Comment: Try `=ROWS(UNIQUE(MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1)))<=2`. It returns a boolean indicating whether a string (cell) contains not more than 2 distinct characters: `MID` combined with `SEQUENCE` returns each character in a row of a vertical vector (column), `UNIQUE` removes duplicates, and `ROWS` returns the number of remaining rows.

Answer (score 1):

### Flag Cells With Fewer Distinct Digits (Characters)

**Digits (Left Table)**

- Returns a boolean indicating whether a string (cell) contains not more than 2 distinct **digits**.

```
=COUNT(SEARCH({0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9},A2))<=2
=COUNT(SEARCH(SEQUENCE(10,,0),A2))<=2
=BYROW(SEARCH(SEQUENCE(,10,0),A2:A11),LAMBDA(r,COUNT(r)<=2))
```

- Note the importance of `SEQUENCE` returning a row (the 1st comma) in the `BYROW` solution.

[image]

**Characters (Right Table)**

- Returns a boolean indicating whether a string (cell) contains not more than 2 distinct **characters**.

```
=ROWS(UNIQUE(MID(A2,SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)),1)))<=2
=BYROW(A2:A11,LAMBDA(r,ROWS(UNIQUE(MID(r,SEQUENCE(LEN(r)),1)))<=2))
```